# google maps api with cordova touch event is ignored

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, google-maps, cordova

I'm working on a **Cordova application**, on Android platform, and I need a map to define some regions through Google maps API.

But when the map is rendered, the touch event is ignored, i.e. i cannot move the map, neither push buttons on it. 
I tried tracing Logcat, but it only shows this:

> V/WebViewInputDispatcher(27743): blockWebkitDraw 
>       V/WebViewInputDispatcher(27743): blockWebkitDraw lockedfalse 
>       V/webview(27743):  singleCursorHandlerTouchEvent -getEditableSupport  FASLE

However, this verbose is shown every time i click on a button or anything... So I'm not sure if this is the problem. 
Any comments on this issue will be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens when you logcat GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener? https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener.html

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. It seems like I was trying to pass a null paramater-I was passing JSON data from Java to JavaScript- to the map and this avoided the ClickListener to be activated on javascript side.